# Having trouble sending String from client socket to server socket, and vice versa

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to create an application that will count the amount of times a button has been clicked. This client would connect to a server, and when the user clicks the button, it should increment the counter on the server. The server should then send back the current amount of clicks to the client. But that's where I'm having a bit of problems.

This is the relevant client-sided code.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try {
                OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
            String target = "";
            bw.write("increment" + "\n");
            bw.flush();

            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String id = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("test: " + id);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

The client stops at:

```
String id = br.readLine();
```

I just want to get the output from the server.

This is the relevant server-sided code.

```
public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is); //Create the input Streams
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String input = br.readLine();
                System.out.println("got input");
                OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
                System.out.println("wrote to out");
                if(input.equals("increment" + "\n")) {
                    totalBets++;
                    System.out.println("inif");
                    bw.write(totalBets);    
                    System.out.println("wrote");
                    bw.flush();
                    System.out.println("flushed");
                    System.out.println("Total Bets: " + totalBets);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log("Error handling client# " + clientNumber + ": " + e);
        } finally {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log("Couldn't close a socket, what's going on?");
            }
            log("Connection with client# " + clientNumber + " closed");
        }
    }
```

I found that it also stops here:

```
String input = br.readLine();
```

I'm just trying to get the bw.write("imcrement") from the client, so the server can increment the counter, and send back the total clicks.

Any help?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you set [TCP_NODELAY](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setTcpNoDelay-boolean-) on the client's socket?  If not then the TCP stack is waiting for the buffer to be full before sending anything.

Comment: When you read a line with `readLine`, it no longer has the `\n` at the end.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I removed the "\n" to the end of both of them. Still no luck. I read online that \n would signal to the input stream that the message is done.

Comment: No, not both of them! You have to write it with the `\n` otherwise it won't be considered a "line", but when you read it, don't compare it with the `\n` as it will be stripped.

Comment: @dsh I set `socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);` no luck.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Ohh! I understand now, my bad. I set the client sided one to \n, and the server went through the whole while loop, flushed and all that. However, the client got stuck at `String id = br.readLine();` It didn't go past there, and the application froze up. Not sure why it wouldn't be accepting the output from the server

Comment: What is the type of `totalBets`?

Comment: `totalBets` is the counter for how many times the client-sided button is clicked. An integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing the `totalBets` value using [`BufferedWriter.write(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write%28int%29).

This interprets the value as a *single character*. So, for example, if `totalBets` is 65, it writes the character `'A'`!

Moreover, it does not add a newline. So the client reads that `'A'` but tries to read more characters as it is trying to read a whole line. Remember that you have to write *lines* to read lines.

Thus, you should replace the part that writes `totalBets` with:

```
bw.write(String.valueOf(totalBets));
bw.newLine();
```

Also remember, as I pointed in a comment, that you have to write a line with a `\n` (or preferably `BufferedWriter.newLine()`), but when you read the line on the other side, the line separator is stripped away, so you should compare the string you expect *without* a `\n`.

Comment: Hooray! It counts now! The only problem I have now is, when I open two clients, the counter starts back at 1 again. For some reason. For some reason, when a new client connects, it creates a new instance of the variable? Maybe? I'm looking into it now

Comment: Can't tell, as it's not part of the code you have shown. But if you don't find where it is, I suggest you post a separate question as the two issues don't seem to be related.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set [TCP_NODELAY](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setTcpNoDelay-boolean-) on the client's socket.  The default is for data to be buffered until it will fill an entire packet.  When the buffer is full, a packet is sent.  However, for this protocol you want the data to be sent immediately so that the server can respond.

I frequently use [wireshark](https://wireshark.org/) when testing and debugging my networking code.  It will show exactly what packets are sent and received.  *(note, however, that on Windows you can not capture from the loopback interface; this is a limitation of Windows and does not apply to other systems)*

Comment: Set `socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);` and it sends the data now. However, the client still gets stuck at `String id = br.readLine();` 

It didn't go past there, and the application freezes up. Not sure why it wouldn't be accepting the output from the server

Comment: Set TCP_NODELAY on the server socket, too, so that when the server sends it is sent immediately instead of waiting for the buffer to fill.  Also, ensure that the server sends end-of-line characters or the `readLine()` will keep waiting until it receives them.

Comment: Also, _ensure that the server sends end-of-line characters or the readLine() will keep waiting until it receives them_ I'm not sure what you mean by this.

Comment: Read the documentation for [`.readLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--): *A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.*  Is your server sending these characters to indicate when the end of the "line" has been received? If it isn't then readLine() will keep waiting until it does receive them.

Comment: Ohhh, I see what you mean. Yes, it does send an an end line \n